# Tkinter - Printnig return function in a label

Tags: python, tkinter

i don't really undestand, why the "results" label is not updating when i click on the button.

If someone can help me to understand!

Thank You

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def add_function(): 
  results.config(n1.get() + n2.get())


root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x100") # Size of the window
root.title("Add Calculator") # Title of the window


main_frame = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
main_frame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N,S,E,W))
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)


n1 = DoubleVar()
n1_entry = Entry(main_frame, width= 10, textvariable= n1)
n1_entry.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=(N))

symbol_add = Label(main_frame, text="+")
symbol_add.grid(column=3, row=1, sticky=(N))

n2 = DoubleVar()
n2_entry = Entry(main_frame, width= 10, textvariable= n2)
n2_entry.grid(column=4, row=1, sticky=(N))

symbol_equal = Button(main_frame, width=10, text="=", command= add_function )
symbol_equal.grid(column=5, row=1, sticky=(N))

results = Label(main_frame, text=add_function(), background="#C0C0C0")
results.grid(column=6, row=1, sticky=(N))

root.mainloop()
```

I've tryed different variant, but it's either i have an error, or the label is printing a random number even before i modify the entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you don't update the label. Returning something from a button command is pointless because the caller isn't your code. It's called from `mainloop` and `mainloop` doesn't know what to do with the return code.

To update the label you must call the `configure` method:

```
results.configure(text=n1.get() + n2.get())
```

Comment: Note that OP has used `text=add_function()` when creating the label.  So the return line is required.

Comment: @acw1668: yes, it's required the first time. I should have addressed that. However, after that they must call `configure` to update the label.

Comment: Thank You for your answer. did really help. 
But now i'm facing this error: "TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()"

Comment: It should be `results.configure(text=n1.get()+n2.get())` instead.

Comment: @acw1668: yes, of course. Thanks for noticing that.